# PyCharm fails to connect to SQLite: SQLITE_BUSY, (database is locked)

Tags: sqlite, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, datagrip

I'm trying to use PyCharm's database tools to connect to a SQLite db.

When I test the connection, it is successful, but when I try to sync to the db, I get:

```
[5] org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked).
```

This happens when the application isn't running, so nothing is currently connected to the db.

EDIT: I've learned that the problem only exists when the db file is on the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Comment: Try to set `Single connection mode` in your data source `Options` tab.

Comment: I have the same issue when a file is in WSL, but I'm using Datagrip.

Comment: @qotsa42 I would expect that DataGrip would behave the same way, sorry to hear this is still an issue.

Answer (score 4):

It's not supported yet, follow the [issue "[Datagrip] Support for WSL paths (SQLite)"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11014)